# How to post a form using fetch in react native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm trying to post the form containing the first_name, last_name, email, password and password_confirmation using react-native fetch api.

```
fetch('http://localhost:3000/auth', {
  method: 'post',
  body: JSON.stringify({
    config_name: 'default',
    first_name: this.state.first_name,
    last_name: this.state.last_name,
    email: this.state.email,
    password: this.state.password,
    password_confirmation: this.state.password_confirmation,
  })
})
```

Output in Rails console

```
Parameters: {"{\"config_name\":\"default\",\"first_name\":\"Piyush\",\"last_name\":\"Chauhan\",\"email\":\"piyushchauhan2011@gmail.com\",\"password\":\"diehard4\",\"password_confirmation\":\"diehard4\"}"=>"[FILTERED]"}
Unpermitted parameter: {"config_name":"default","first_name":"Piyush","last_name":"Chauhan","email":"piyushchauhan2011@gmail.com","password":"diehard4","password_confirmation":"diehard4"}
```

So, its posting the whole value as string and rails is parsing the string as a variable. I want to strip out the "{" from the json response. How to do it ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

so if I understand you well, you want it to post the same string but just without the curly braces?

If that's the case, you can just strip them from the string.

> .replace(/{|}/gi, "")

so that would look as follows

```
fetch('http://localhost:3000/auth', {
method: 'post',
body: JSON.stringify({
  config_name: 'default',
  first_name: this.state.first_name,
  last_name: this.state.last_name,
  email: this.state.email,
  password: this.state.password,
  password_confirmation: this.state.password_confirmation,
  }).replace(/{|}/gi, "")
})
```

Answer (score 2):

```
const m = encodeURIComponent(userEmail);
const p = encodeURIComponent(userPassword);
const requestBody = `email=${m}&pass=${p}`;
fetch(`http://server.com`, {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' },
    body: requestBody
})
```

Comment: Please provide detail and explain more